# scroll view in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, scroll

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use scroll view on iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/617796/how-to-use-scroll-view-on-iphone)

hi everyone,
i was working with the scroll view , i want to scroll a simple page , how can it be done on iphone, i mean what changes we need to do on interface builder , and what class and code is to be added.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to drag a `UIScrollView` in your file.xib then a `UIView` which will be definitely longer than the typical `UIView`. Then drag that `UIView` into `UIScrollView`.

Now drag that `UIScollView` in the `UIView` which is linked to the FilesOwner's View.

Now in your `file.h` make an outlet of `UIScrollView`

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrolldown;
```

then link it with the `UIScrollView` in the InterfaceBuilder.

then in your `viewDidLoad` method write these lines.

```
[scrolldown setScrollEnabled:YES];
[scrolldown setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 650)];  //(320, 650) is the size of View which is inside the UIScrollView.
```

Comment: @Adil Soomro:hey tried your method , but its not scrolling.

Comment: For me it is working.  Just confirm that, There is UIView that hosts a UIScrollView, and the UIScrollView holds another UIView which is larger than screen. The most parent UIView is connected to FilesOwner's View.

Comment: u mean i have to place a UIView  first on xib , then a UIScrollView and then another UIView?

Comment: Yep! the first UiView will be connected to the FilesOwner's view. FilesOwner's View is responsible to display the contents which is placed inside it.

Comment: ok first we have to add uiview and then i have to add my text fields and labels then scroll view and uiview right?

Comment: Let me explain through variables... UIView parent, UIScrollView scrollView, UIView largeView. Now place all your text fields ect on largeView. place largeView into scrollView, and drage scrollView into parent. Connect parent to the FilesOwner's View.

Answer (score 1):

### Add in .h file

```
@interface ScrollImageViewController : UIViewController {
UIScrollView *scrollView;  
}         
@property(nonatomic,retain)UIScrollView *scrollView;  
@end
```

### and in .m add the following line in viewdidload

```
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 800);
```

also synthesize the property

```
@synthesize scrollView;
```